# NSDictionary and Objective-C block quirk

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I initialise an NSDictionary with keys NSString and objects blocks, like so.

```
NSDictionary * d =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  ^ ( int p1 ){ some code }, @"a",
  ^ ( int p1, NSString * p2 ){ some code }, @"b",
nil];
```

When I retrieve some of these blocks it fails *on retrieval*, ie

```
someVar = [d objectForKey:@"b"];
```

fails even though there is an object associated with `@"b"`.

When I log the dictionary I note that the objects I can retrieve are stored as `__NSMallocBlock__` and those that fail are stored as `__NSStackBlock__`. Although the `__NSStackBlock__` seems valid the debugger shows that it wraps a `nil` block.

**Edit**

This is crazy for two reasons.

First I am unable to generate the error using just the snippets above. However, if the block also contains a reference to any weak pointer, it does result in the error.

Thus to generate the error you need

```
__weak NSString * p = @"ab"; // Some weak pointer
NSDictionary * d =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  ^ ( int p1 ){ some code }, @"a",
  ^ ( int p1, NSString * p2 ){ NSLog( @"%p", p ); }, @"b",
nil];
```

while the snippet given earlier works without any trouble.

I've tried the failing snippet with a weak pointer to self or to some arbitrary string as above and both fail. Note that even if the pointer is not valid that log should work without any issues.

Secondly, as mentioned above, the error occurs when you *retrieve* the object! Even if I do nothing with the block, just retrieve it from the dictionary, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the block parameters.

The compiler and ARC stores blocks differently based on the block's parameters. To fix this create strong pointers to the blocks and then store those pointers in the dictionary, thus

```
blockVarA = ^ ( pars ){ some code };  // Strong pointers
blockVarB = ^ ( pars ){ some code };

NSDictionary * d =
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  blockVarA, @"a",
  blockVarB, @"b",
nil];
```

will ensure all are stored as `__NSMallocBlock__` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh, yet another bug in Apple's block handling and we thought they'd fixed them all years ago.

First report your original code at the site feedbackassistant.apple.com – the chances that they'll fix it are slim but please do it anyway. (Feel free to include the code below as a version that is handled correctly.)

Second you can use more modern code:

```
NSDictionary * d = @{ @"a" : ^ ( int p1 ){ NSLog(@"%d", p1 * arg); },
                      @"b" : ^ ( int p1, NSString * p2 ){ NSLog(@"%d, '%@'"
                    };
```

which Apple does appear to compile correctly (and looking at the underling mechanisms and types it is possible to see why this is different from your code and doesn't have the same compiler bug).

***Postscript***

You are correct, Apple does store blocks differently depending on certain factors – this is a compiler optimisation and, like all such optimisations, should not be visible to the programmer accept in improved code (performance, size, etc.).

However for reasons Apple never explained they decided to release the block implementation with this optimisation visible to the programmer, and indeed required the programmer to add specific code to deal with it. Over time they made adding that code unnecessary and finally documented "job done".

In Swift, which also uses ARC, they seem to have learnt from their experience with Objective-C and implemented block handling correctly through a combination of optimisations and language-level annotations – one could have a debate over the necessity/benefit/cost/choice/etc. of the latter but we can say Apple isn't unique in making the choice and it is certainly a massive improvement over where they started with blocks in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks CRD! Apple never explains ... especially if the modern approach works I think this will get 0 appetite. But the mere fact that the modern and my approach differs shows me there is still some work to be done there somewhere. I know Swift uses ARC and am really very surprised that this works in Swift.

Comment: @CRD comment deleted. You're right, I actually mixed two things together and I was wrong.

Comment: @CRD this opens a can of worms (for me) ... I have so many questions but let me be as brief as possible. I agree that ```id``` should not require ```copy``` under ARC. But is the bug for Apple or for clang's inbox? If the ```id``` derives from ```NSObject``` I'd give it to Apple but a block pointer should go to clang? It seems the ```id``` gets wrapped in ```__NSMallocBlock__``` which I suppose derives from ```NSObject```. Even is ```NSObject``` gets involved this seems more compiler / clang territory.

Comment: I re-read the [ARC - Blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks) docs: _When a block pointer type is converted to a non-block pointer type (such as `id`), `Block_copy` is called. ... A block pointer is implicitly converted to `id` when it is passed to a function as a variadic argument._ Definitely a bug.

Comment: @skaak - You send the bug to feedbackassistant.apple.com, clang is essentially Apple's compiler and they write and ship the Objective-C (and Swift) compilers and designed and implemented the ARC and block specifications.

Comment: Seems that they fixed it for C (not Obj-C variadic message) functions [6 months ago, Dec 2019](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/a0a670614a36f1686c5086033bef85800128cf66#diff-0d4e154f927adee7eb243c2df0e59d18).

Comment: @zrzka - The ARC documentation was also updated sometime between 12 & 24 Dec adding the last para of §7.6 emphasising the handling of blocks, `id`, and variadics. I don't believe this was a change in semantics, just a clarification, though some of the past debate has been over the possible interpretations of the spec in this and other documents so its good to see Apple move to clear up any misunderstandings – now they just need to fix the last bugs in the implementation.

Comment: Yep, this paragraph about `id` & variadics in the docs is part of the commit I mentioned/linked in the previous comment. I reported it as well, more reports, better chance to have it fixed.

Comment: The bug is still in the latest beta, hopefully the bug reports arising from the this question will get it resolved, but only on Catalina+. Good find on the patch @zrzka, it wasn't hard for them to fix (I had thought they fixed cornet cases like variadis ages ago).

Comment: @CRD I am struggling to recreate this bug! If I use my project's rather complex code I can easily do it just by creating the dictionary with the strong pointers or with the 'inline' blocks as described here. Been trying on and off for the last few days. Based on your comments I presume you are able to do it? Can you share that code? I can share my attempt which does not generate the error.

Comment: @skaak here's an attachment from my feedback describing this bug - https://cln.sh/aayfj6

Comment: @zrzka thanks! In my project, where I can generate the error, I also use a weak pointer to self but in the simplified project where I am unable to generate it I do not use a weak pointer to self. That code looks pretty much like what CRD posted or what I posted earlier, just two blocks with either just an ```int``` and an ```int``` and ```NSString``` pointer. I haven't done anything yet but it seems the weak pointer to self is also needed to generate the error!

Comment: @zrzka thanks a lot - that helped me to generate the error. See the edit I've added based on that.

Comment: @CRD with a bit of help from zrzka ... have reported the bug.